# Block SSH hop based on traffic origin?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

Is there a way to find where the SSH traffic origins from?

We have two servers A and B.
A is on a private network.
B has 2 nics, private and public.

A can SSH into B and B can SSH into A
problem is, clients are connecting from outside world X into B then SSHing in to A.
Is there any way to have A block SSH traffic if it's not originated from a known host?

I want:
local -> A

A -> B

A -> B -> local

local -> B

local -> B -> A

local -> A -> B

B -> local

B -> A -> local

public -> B

but not public -> B -> A

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? A user could circumvent the restrictions (assuming some complicated multi-host IDS system that could track active SSH sessions over multiple hosts) by ssh public -> B -> local and then scheduling a cron or at job to run a future ssh local -> A after they log out.

Comment: You might be able to rig something with iptables, selinux and confining users.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent users from accessing server A from outside the network, home. But they are allowed to access B from home. access should only be blocked if they are originating from an outside network.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use iptables or even /etc/hosts.{allow,deny} to allow the address you want on Server A and then on Server B only allow Server A? Why not just whitelist the IP's you allow and deny all the rest? Another thing I find helpful is to put SSH on a non-default port.

On another note, you can view /var/log/secure to see the originating IP.

Answer (score 0):

If a user is able to SSH on to server B from the "outside" and then managed to SSH over to A, the logs on Server A would show the source IP as Server B NOT the users remote IP. You would therefore not be able to tell whether the SSH session was from an internal or external user.

You need to lock down external access to Server B so that only specific IP addresses to be able to connect (e.g. with iptables `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s YourIP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`) **and** improve security on the servers with either strong passwords or SSH keys.